# figwheel doesn't start in reagent project on windows7

Tags: java, maven, clojure, leiningen, figwheel

I'm trying to run figwheel for reagent project:

> lein new reagent app
>  cd app
>  lein figwheel

After that I'm receiving following output:

```
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.commons:commons-compress:pom:1.3 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Received fatal alert: protocol_version
Could not transfer artifact com.yahoo.platform.yui:yuicompressor:pom:2.4.7 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Received fatal alert: protocol_version
Could not transfer artifact com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:pom:v20141120 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Received fatal alert: protocol_version<br>
Could not transfer artifact commons-io:commons-io:pom:2.4 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Received fatal alert: protocol_version
Could not transfer artifact org.clojure:core.async:pom:0.1.338.0-5c5012-alpha from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Received fatal alert: protocol_version<br>
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.<br>
```

I have no idea what to do with this issue next. I've checked environment variable, but I don't have any 'http_proxy' variable.
If you have an understanding what to do next to fix the issue, I'll be appreciated

https://youtu.be/rAcaJG8OeKw

Update:
on command

> lein new figwheel-main app -- --reagent

I receive

```
 Failed to resolve version for figwheel-main:lein-template:jar:RELEASE: Could not find metadata figwheel-main:lein-template/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\user\.m2\repository
)
Failed to resolve version for figwheel-main:lein-template:jar:RELEASE: Could not find metadata figwheel-main:lein-template/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\user\.m2\repository
)
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies, file system permissions, or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
Could not find template figwheel-main on the classpath.
```

Comment: I seem to recall having trouble recently with the stock reagent template even on linux. I've switched to using the figwheel template `lein new figwheel-main app -- --reagent`, but that may not be your problem. Unfortunately I don't have a windows install handy to test on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my silly mistake. I was sure that I have curl and wget tools on my laptop, but I haven't. So, after installing them on my Window7 I've got all I want.